# Why my facebook android sdk login called two times?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, callback

I am working with the Facebook SDK, the problem is the FormSubmit function has run two times. It is called by the `getView` function which is called by `onCreateView` and by the `statusCallback`, how to fix it?

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements LoginListener {
    public View rootView;
    public ImageView HomeBg;
    public ImageView buttonLoginLogout;
    public TextView chi;
    public TextView eng;
    public ColorStateList oldColor;
    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public EasyTracker tracker = null;

    //Facebook login
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
        prefs =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("memberData", 0);

        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        buttonLoginLogout = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_connectFB);
        eng = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_eng);
        chi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chi);

        if (Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("TC")) {
            chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = eng.getTextColors();
        } else {
            eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = chi.getTextColors();

        }

        eng.setOnClickListener(setChangeLangListener("EN"));
        chi.setOnClickListener(setChangeLangListener("TC"));

        //Facebook login
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

       updateView();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Landing Page " + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()));
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStop(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // get request

            if (!session.getAccessToken().equals(prefs.getString("token", "")))
                new FormSubmit(getActivity(),this,tracker).execute("login", session.getAccessToken());
            else
                onTaskComplete(prefs.getString("token", ""),prefs.getString("memberId", ""));

        } else {
            buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_connect_facebook);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }
    }

    public OnClickListener setChangeLangListener(final String lang) {
        OnClickListener changeLangListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());

                if (Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("TC") && lang.equals("EN")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchEN", null).build());
                    config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                    chi.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.white));
                } else if (Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("EN") && lang.equals("TC")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchTC", null).build());
                    config.locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
                    eng.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.white));
                }

                getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                onConfigurationChanged(config);
            }
        };
        return changeLangListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
      getActivity().finish();
      startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String token, String memberId) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "t:" + token + "m:" + memberId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_take_a_selfie);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) { 
                ((LandingPage)getActivity()).tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskFailure(String errorMsg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void saveMemberInfo(String token, String memberId){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("token", token);
        editor.putString("memberId", memberId);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: All HTML requests have a response, if this is connecting to facebook it's likely that you're getting the Reponse + Postback, which will make your event fire twice. I'm not familiar with the Facebook SDK but I'd take a look into the API of the functions you're using.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I follow the sdk sample provided by facebook sdk in the folder sample/SessionLoginSample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your SessionStatusCallback() method like below and check the output.

**And if it works, then mark this as accepted answer.**

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            updateView();
        }
    }
}
```

`SessionStatusCallback()` method will called everytime when your session is getting changed from one state to another.

Before getting login in Facebook, your SessionState is `SessionState.CLOSED`. When you are trying to get login in Facebook and authentication step is succeeded, then your session change into  `SessionState.OPENING` and this time your `SessionStatusCallback()` method get executed.

But in current situation your session is not opened completely, it is in process of opening. So, after this when your session is getting open completely, session state changed to `SessionState.OPENED` and thus your `SessionStatusCallback()` method is called once again.

Thats why changed your `SessionStatusCallback()` method as I described above and it will work perfectly.

Comment: The problem happens because you add a listener that call updateView(), but this facebook sample already call updateView() in OnCreate(). You can divide it in two methods, and probably do what you want in that if  statement @Vivek Bansal sugested.

Answer (score 1):

You try to restore/open session in `onCreateView()`. So when the session is ready, your callback is called, thus `updateView()` is called.

A quick fix is to call `updateView()` `onResume()` instead of `onCreateView()`. Then, inside `updateView()`, check and return immediately if `isAdded()` returns `false`. Because in that case, `updateView()` is called by your callback at the moment that views are not ready. Please take `UserSettingsFragment` in FB SDK as an example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/UserSettingsFragment.java#L370.

Also, I would try to load session `onActivityCreated()` instead of `onCreateView()` to make sure the activity is created and ready. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/FacebookFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running the same request twice.

Remove

```
updateView();
```

From onCreate as it will be called anyway when statusCallback is triggered